# two keys one value in android

Tags: java, list

How do I implement the following data ?

```
somelisttype <int>obj ;

obj 0,0 => val0
obj 0,1 => val1
obj 0,2 => val2
obj 1,0 => val8
obj 2,0 => val9
obj 2,1 => val10
```

`0,0 ; 0,1` are the keys ( or in other way the row index or column index.)

I would like to have following functionality ..

```
obj 0.add(val11) == obj 0,3 => val11
obj 3.add(val12) == obj 3,0 => val12

obj 2.length => 2
obj 3.length => 1

obj 0,2 => val2
```

ValXX => are values and not objects ( would be integers )

I don't want to create 2d array since I don't know length of total obj or individual obj0,obj1

What variable type can be used for this in android ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's about `List<List<Integer>>`?

You can't avoid the generic type to be an object here but since cast from `Integer` to `int` is implicit you would see any difference in use.

**Update**

Okay here it is:

```
MyList l = new MyList();
l.set(0, 0, 1);
l.set(1, 0, 2);
l.set(1, 1, 3);

Log.d("TAG", l.get(0, 0) + " " + l.get(1, 0) + " " + l.get(1, 1));
```

Here the implementation (o course you have to make sure that used index is right, so you can't add index 1 when 0 is not already set):

```
class MyList {

    private List<List<Integer>> mList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

    public void set(int i, int k, int value) {
        List<Integer> list;

        if (i == mList.size()) {
            list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            mList.add(i, list);
        } else {
            list = mList.get(i);
        }

        if (k == list.size()) {
            list.add(value);
        } else {
            list.set(k, value);
        }
    }

    public int get(int i, int k) {
        return mList.get(i).get(k);
    }
}
```

Comment: but cast from int to Integer is not implicit.. so when I add data I must create a new obj of type Integer for each entry I make.

Comment: also I cannot directly do obj1.add(8889) .. I have to make another list objtemp.add(8889) , then obj.add(objtemp) . Hope you got the problem.

Comment: Casts between primitive types and their wrapper classes are implizit. It's called [auto-boxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html). You can use a `Integer` where you use `int` but you will get a `NullPointerException` when your value is `null`.

Comment: adding the data becomes vague.... `I have to make another list objtemp.add(8889) , then obj.add(objtemp) . Hope you got the problem.`

Comment: yup perfect .. thanks.. `i == mList.size()` would be `i => mList.size()`

Comment: Not quite right since this would give you an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap which is based on key value pair.

You find a simple eg over [here](http://www.roseindia.net/javatutorials/javahashmap.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

This is really a basic Java question, and has little to do with Android. You might want to change your tags to get better answers. A `List` of `List<Integer>` will probably do, unless you need to put/get by key, in which case you need a `HashMap` with a composite key, that holds two integers.